# "Column X cannot be null" happening when that column is not null

Tags: mysql

On the below table, this works

```
mysql> UPDATE DiscussionPost SET timestamp = timestamp WHERE id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

but this doesn't

```
mysql> UPDATE DiscussionPost SET timestamp = timestamp;
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'quality' cannot be null
```

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE DiscussionPost
(
    id BIGINT                 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp     DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    quality       FLOAT       NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ...
```

verifying

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| timestamp     | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quality       | float       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
...
```

Checking the data

```
mysql> select quality, timestamp from DiscussionPost;
+---------+----------------------------+
| quality | timestamp                  |
+---------+----------------------------+
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.503880 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.511738 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.515614 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.520277 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.537947 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.545949 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.576927 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.594577 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.599863 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.616189 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.628171 |
|       0 | 2023-12-02 10:37:38.633610 |
+---------+----------------------------+
```

So, `quality` is not null in either the schema, the data, nor the query.

Why am I getting

> `Column 'quality' cannot be null` for `UPDATE DiscussionPost SET timestamp = timestamp`?

Why am I not getting this error when I restrict to `where id=1`?

Comment: Any triggers associated with the `DiscussionPost` table ? Can you reproduce your issue in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) ?

Comment: @spraff not able to reproduce in mysql 8

Comment: @ErgestBasha it was a trigger issue, thank you. Would you like to make that a formal answer?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a trigger, which needed an `IFNULL(...,0)` to prevent it inserting a NULL when data was missing.